# opening my react native project via expo app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to open my first created react native project with expo app via my Android Phone Redmi note 7 pro. I just installed node.js expo today only.  But I am getting error as ::

```
could not load exp://192.168.1.131:1900 Network response timed out.
```

error log shows::

```
uncaught error: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to /192.168.1.131 (port 1900) from / 192.168.0.121 (port 48356) after 10000ms
```

Also in the browser it is showing::

```
watch mode is not supported in this environment.
```

How to solve this error? I have connected my mobile using hotspot from my laptop where I am developing my project.

Comment: I dont know if you can run it in the same hotspot - did you just tried to connect it to the same wifi (network) ?

Comment: @yesIamFaded I tried via same network also, still getting the same error. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

**Change your network privacy:-**
change your home network to be 'private' as for some reason it had designated it 'public'